# Openero-Mobile Where is the table name definition?

Tags: android, odoo, openerp-7

I am developing an app for some openerp modules in android and I keep getting this error **when trying to create the products module**,

> "2239-2258/com.openerp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table:".

I've tried product_product and product.product with no luck.

Can you tell me exactly where is the definition of the table name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table name, go with **product_template**, but be aware, that entries made only there will not be enough.

Comment: thanks for responding, but i didn't make myself clear enough. The sqlite table is not product_product. That's why it gives me this error, no such table: product_product.